# How to get the city name and state/province from marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

searched the forum for a few days and i still can't get my head around it...

all i can find on this site is the option to get the full formatted adress from a marker.. 
(Like this: 228 Barbary Coast Trail, San Francisco, California 94102, United States)

I'm developing an application that requires only

- A city or village name
- A State/province or area name
- The country name

(The other stuff is not needed because the rest is run through lat/lon coordinates).

On login i want them to

- Set there coordinates via a marker on google map 
  (onclick and only 1 marker, the second click for a marker would remove the first marker, not sure if i will be using the sensor or not....)

The values of the marker updated in a hidden text field of a form Lat/Lon and city/state/Country

All is working but i cannot get the city name etc to appear in the textboxes... (unhidden the textboxes in this example)

Here is the code i got so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas {height:600px;width:800px}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var markersArray = [];

    function initMap()
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.850258199721495, 2.373046875);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        // add a click event handler to the map object
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event)
        {
            // place a marker
            placeMarker(event.latLng);

            // display the lat/lng in your form's lat/lng fields
            document.getElementById("latFld").value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("lngFld").value = event.latLng.lng();


        });
    }
    function placeMarker(location) {
        // first remove all markers if there are any
        deleteOverlays();

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location, 
            map: map
        });

        // add marker in markers array
        markersArray.push(marker);

        //map.setCenter(location);
    }

    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
    function deleteOverlays() {
        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        markersArray.length = 0;
        }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap()">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<input type="text" id="latFld">
<input type="text" id="lngFld">
<input type="text" id="City">
<input type="text" id="Area">
</body>
</html>
```

Should be easy but...."i think i twisted my brains on this one...."

Comment: Here you can find [Reverse Geocoding docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: This only explains how to get the full adress and is not very helpfull when you need just the city/state/country... sorry :-( the above is a working example but it misses this feature....

Comment: Thanks! used json to get the values into a array and splitting it up again.... then extract the results!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the results by using RESULT_TYPE ='country' for getting country.
see the doc for RESULT_TYPE.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=country&key=API_KEY

Comment: Used Reverse Geocoding with json to get the values into a array and then splitting it up again...